# Compute Mean square error between each pair of 31 arrays on imagej or excel

Tags: excel, imagej, mse

I want to compute the Mean Square Error between each pair of 31 arrays of size 1024 containing gray values of profiles of lines on 31 images.

My arrays are full_yval1 to full_yval31 and i want to find out a way on imagej to code this on a macro and to get à 2D matrix (31by31) or an array of 961 (31*31).
i tried :

```
MSE = newArray(961);
for (i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
    for (j = i; j < 32; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < full_yval1.length; k++) {
            MSE[i][j] = sqrt(pow(full_yvali[k] - full_yvalj[k],2)/full_yval1.length);
        }
    }
}
```

but this is not functiooning in Imagej.

I also have the csv file of results but i dont know how to do this on excel too.

Can somebody help me please.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code? What have you tried, what did not work

Comment: i have edited my post and added what i tried to do. thanks

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)